# How to implement Optimistic Locking in an Azure Mobile Service?

Tags: javascript, sql, azure, azure-mobile-services, optimistic-locking

I have an Azure Mobile Service backend for my app. I use MSSQL in a very out-of-the-box manner. However, I have multiple clients that can access same objects at the same time in theory. Adequate solution for me would be to use Optimistic Locking to avoid any further concurrency problems.

So my question is this. I have a Timestamp that's filled in by the backend. My question is whether there's a neat way to handle fetching the "old version" of the item in the process or am I forced to manually query the object from the database - or whether it's possible to easily incorporate the date constraint in the query similar to

```
function update(item, user, request) {
    query.where...
    request.execute();
}
```

But there is no query in update? Performance is important for my app as I expect there to be a lot of queries.

Answer (score 0):

Optimistic locking really doesn't make sense for the web.  Your read and update operations are stateless and be part of independent requests (brushing up on HTTP might be a good idea).

That's not to say that each request can't use a transaction (see the `mssql` object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554212.aspx).  But from a fundamentally distributed web application, introducing a transaction across multiple requests is generally a bad architectural decision.  (See CAP Theorem).

You could simulate transactions or "sagas" using Azure Queues and messages like commands and events to change new state in your database to manage locking records by user.  Or you could simply have another table to manage record locks for your existing table.  Either way, you have to make record locking explicit in your application logic because read and update are different requests and the inherent nature of stateless web and distributed computing.